# Is it possible that data is still encrypted even when you intercept TLS?

Tags: tls, man-in-the-middle, proxy, tls-intercept

I've recently set up a `mitmproxy` on my phone and it seems to work fine. It intercepts that request for `https` websites and I can view their content.

But I'm trying to intercept data from a banking app I have on my phone. The connection works perfectly fine and I can see all of the requests that get sent from my phone on the console. Except I don't know how to make sense of the response or the payload.  It looks a bit like it's encrypted but I'm not sure if it is.

Can the data still be encrypted even though I've installed the `mitm` cert and am able to view other `https` responses and payloads?

**Updated**

As pointed out by schroeder and Robert, the response is likely encoded rather than encrypted. After going through the common encoding algorithms: gzip, deflate, and trying to decompress the payload, I'm unable to figure out which encoding was used for this. Here are some screenshots. I was wondering if someone could point out possibly what encoding was used or whether I'm still stuck with the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

[image: the request payload from mitmproxy]

Comment: This looks like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You can't read the packets, so you're asking about encryption. It's possible that the payload is encoded. And it's possible that there is application-level encryption.

Comment: Applying a custom encryption on data before sending them through a TLS channel is possible but unusual. More likely is that you don't understand the used encoding or the data is compressed in a way that mitmproxy does not understand. Check the headers of requests and response for possible compression indications and decompile the app to get the used data format.

Comment: hi @Robert so i looked into the request headers and because of the presence of `accept-encoding: gzip` , i tried decompressing the payload with a gzip decompressor online but it said the format wasn't a gzip. As for the decompiling the app its still in progress but was wondering if you had some pointers in response of the attached screenshot

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Especially for banking: banking has to transmit a bunch of data across *unencrypted* connections (think credit card readers) so it can do its own encryption. You might want to try decompiling/reverse-engineering the app

Comment: That's a ***field*** that has encoded/encrypted data. So, your question needs to be completely reframed. It has nothing to do with TLS. You are successfully seeing the unencrypted payload from TLS. Your question ***now*** is "what's this field?" And that's no longer a security question.

Comment: Your screenshot shows the request but you are always talking about the response. Just a mistake or is the data in the screenshot unrelated? The screen shot most likely shows a base64 encoded data (the `=` sign at the end is a good indicator for base64 encoded data).